# while calling update web method in jquery ajax its firing error "undefined " at data parameters while debugging it in chrome develo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

### error in jquery function can u tell me whats wrong in this query

```
update: function (options) {                   
                               $.ajax({
                                   type: "POST",
                                   url: url1,
                                   cache:false,
                                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                   data: JSON.stringify({  "PersonID": "'+$('#personid').val()+'", "ZipCode": "'+$('#zipcode').val()+'", "FirstName": "'+$('#firstname').val()+'", "LastName": "'+$('#lastname').val()+'"}),



      dataType: "json",
                                       success: function (

result) {
                                       if (result.d != "success") {
                                           alert(result.d);
                                       }

                                   dataSource.read();

                               },

                               error: function (result) {
                                   alert(result.Id);

                               }

                           });

                   },
```

### my web method

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

        public static string UpdateData(int PersonID,int Zipcode,string FirstName,string LastName)
        {
        //DataSet ds = null;
        //return ds;
        string strResult = "";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Database=parmesh;Data Source=.;Trusted_Connection=true");
        SqlCommand updateData = new SqlCommand();

        updateData.Connection = con1;
        updateData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        updateData.CommandText = "updatetable";
        updateData.Parameters.Add("@personid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(PersonID);
        updateData.Parameters.Add("@zipcode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Zipcode);
        updateData.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(FirstName);
        updateData.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(LastName);

        updateData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = updateData;
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        dt = dataSet.Tables[0];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            strResult = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][0]);
            //strResult = strResult.Replace("<error>", "");
            //strResult = strResult.Replace("</error>", "");
            // RenderXML(dt, strResult);
        }
        return strResult;
    }
```

Comment: String concatenation for data is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your `data` is wrong I think.

Insted of:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "PersonID": "'+$('#personid').val()+'",
    "ZipCode": "'+$('#zipcode').val()+'",
    "FirstName": "'+$('#firstname').val()+'",
    "LastName": "'+$('#lastname').val()+'"
}),
```

try

```
data: {
    "PersonID": $('#personid').val(),
    "ZipCode": $('#zipcode').val(),
    "FirstName": $('#firstname').val(),
    "LastName": $('#lastname').val()
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting you're data from html form, i'll suggest for you to use **$.serialize()** function from jQuery api, outside the ajax call you get your form element and serialize it, example:

```
var form=$("#your_form"), ajaxData= form.serialize();
$.ajax({
   ...
   data: ajaxData,
   ...
});
```